# How to handle of a python 'tkinter' GUI statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, uibutton

Firstly, I am unfamiliar with "Tkinter" python module. I create a GUI where there are two buttons. One is **Browse** which will show a dialog box when I press it, and another is **Convert**, which will convert an image. So, when I run the whole code, it supposes to show a primary interface as **demo 1**. But when I run the script, it directly pulls me to the file browse dialog box as **demo 2**.

> How to solve this issue!!!

demo 1:
[image: The UI I want]

demo 2:
[image: The UI what I am getting after running the code]

my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import numpy as np


def showImage():
    fln = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= os.getcwd(), title = "Choose Image", 
        filetypes= (("JPG files", "*.jpg*"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    img = Image.open(fln)
    img.thumbnail((350,350))
    img  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    lbl.configure(image= img)
    lbl.image = img
    return fln

root = Tk()
root.title("Browse Image")
root.geometry('300x450')
lbl = Label(root)
lbl.pack()



def convertImg(fln):
    img = Image.open(fln)
    imageConvert = np.asarray(img)
    print(imageConvert)


frm = Frame(root)
frm.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx= 15, pady= 15)

#first button
btn1 = Button(frm, text= "Browse", command= lambda : showImage())
btn1.pack()


path = showImage() #I think the problem is here form this line
# second button
btn2 = Button(frm, text= "Convert", command= lambda : convertImg(path))
btn2.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I find out an answer which is shown below. I just **declare the variable globally** which contains the path and then access it in another function of button two named "ConvertImg".

Solved code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import numpy as np


def showImage():
    global fln
    fln = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= os.getcwd(), title = "Choose Image", 
        filetypes= (("JPG files", "*.jpg*"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    img = Image.open(fln)
    img.thumbnail((350,350))
    img  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    lbl.configure(image= img)
    lbl.image = img
    

root = Tk()
root.title("Browse Image")
root.geometry('300x450')
lbl = Label(root)
lbl.pack()



def convertImg():
    fln1 = fln
    img = Image.open(fln1)
    imageConvert = np.asarray(img)
    print(imageConvert)


frm = Frame(root)
frm.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx= 15, pady= 15)

#first button
btn1 = Button(frm, text= "Choose Another Image", command= lambda : showImage())
btn1.pack()


# path = showImage()
# second button
btn2 = Button(frm, text= "Convert Your Selected Image", command= lambda : convertImg())
btn2.pack()


root.mainloop()
```